# android best practices for writing media

Tags: android, android-storage

I want to allow the user to be able to record quite a few small recording snippets and the app to be able to play them back. These recordings are probably pretty app specific - I can't see the user wanting to access them in other contexts - although I would like to have an export function just in case.

I'm finding the documentation a little confusing, especially due to pre android 6 and post android 11 differences. As far as I can see, I have two choices*:

- Use app specific external storage
- Use shared storage -  mediastore

I have some specific queries for each one:

- When experimenting with specific external storage by creating a file using `File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),"temp.3gp"`, I find that it is written to `[root]/android/data/com.example.myApp/files/Music/temp.3gp` (where root is empty for my phone, or /storage/emulated/0/ for the emulator.

  - Is this the normal file structure for android external storage?
  - When I try to open this file in the android studio emulator device file explorer, the folder storage/emulator/0/android/data says permission denied and won't show contents. How do I access this?
  - As far as I understand, in order for this method to work, I need to ask for write permission, but not for read permission? (I have only included write permission and it seems to work).
  - Is this what is meant by scoped storage?
- If I use shared storage (i.e. mediastore) in this case, I do not need to ask for permissions? But presumably, there will be lots of clutter on the user's side, since they might store music / more personal things there?

*One could use internal storage, but as far as I understand, this is discouraged for potentially many media files.

Comment: `, I find that it is written to root/android/data/com.example.myApp/files/Music/temp.3gp` Root? Where did you see that? You mean: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myApp/files/Music/temp.3gp ?

Comment: File explorers have no access to that app specific path.

Comment: `the folder storage/emulator/0/data says permission denied` Such a folder does not exist to begin with.

Comment: `As far as I understand, in order for this method to work, I need to ask for write permission, ` No. No permissions needed for app specific storage locations. No read. No write.

Comment: 1) I have amended my question to define what I meant by root - I had thought it was obvious I meant the root directory. 2) But my question is: can I access the app's external storage using the file explorer? I can access it on the phone emulator itself using the file app. 3) Obviously I mistyped the directory - I have corrected it to match the one above. 4) Ok - can you provide me with the documentation saying this, I can't find it?

Comment: Please define "best".

Comment: I would hope you could do that. That is the point of the question. Sorry if this sounds stand offish.

Comment: `I had thought it was obvious I meant the root directory. ` ? Root? There is no root directory. Please reread my comment as i told you what there is instead.

Comment: Or reread my comment as I also told you what it is.

Comment: `As far as I can see, I have two choices*:` Well if you want the users of your app to be able to use file managers to see your files then write them to public directories. Like Documents, Download, DCIM and such. Or to subdirs in them which you create first.

Comment: `(where root is empty for my phone,` Not at all. Where did you see that? Use the File class to tell you full path: file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Any storage system has a root directory. It is not in the spirit of the question to quibble about what exactly root is - you will find it when you use context.getExternalFilesDir(). Please, if you are going to keep commenting, answer in the spirit of this rather easy question and clear up the misunderstandings I have.